# Video compression programmatically in android without using any third party library's

Tags: java, android, video, compression

I have a 300 mb file in my sd card i want to compress the size of the video without using any other third party library's like ffmpeg,mp4parser. is it possible in android ?

Comment: What do you exactly mean with "compress". Do you want to render it to lower quality, so the file will be smaller or is zipping it an option?

Comment: i want to reduce the size of video below 100 mb, if video is in any size. @Fildor

Comment: Can you specify which format / container etc ... Android is a little bit limited on that. Which Android version is the target platform? Is it ok to lose frames?

Comment: Did I get that : ANY Size video -> < 100 MB ?? I think is not possible without losing frames. The bigger the source the more you lose.

Comment: Thanks for you reply.Any video format for example mp4.If quality loss it's ok.If change in resolution also not a problem.Just i want to reduce the size of a video into below 100 mb. Android version above API level 10.

Comment: You should add all these information to your question. I am not sure if this is possible without 3rd party.

Comment: ok without using ffmpeg is there any other third party lib is there to achive this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65062/discussion-between-babu-and-fildor).

Comment: did you found any lib to compress video faster ?